# string types not allowed - axml Xamarin android

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017

How can I fix the following error?

> string types not allowed (at 'id' with value ' @+id/phone number text')

**Main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:text="Enter Phoneword"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id=" @+id/PhoneNumberText"
    android:text="1-855-XAMARIN" />
<Button
    android:text="Translate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TranslateButton" />
<Button
    android:text="Call"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/callbutton" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The id declaration for `android:id=" @+id/PhoneNumberText"` has a space in front of `@+id/PhoneNumberText`.

Remove the space and it should work:

`android:id="@+id/PhoneNumberText"`